# HTML Offline Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, gps, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with an WLAN Dongle providing a Hotspot.
I connect my Laptop/Mobile to this Hotspot.
The Raspberry Pi has a webserver which delivers a website with its own coordinates via GPS.

So, now my problem: When I am connecting to the Accesspoint I no longer have access to the internet. My first thought was to display the current position on a Google Maps in the Browser but this will not work without an Internet Connection (due Tiles and stuff).

In fact I am not interested in the map it self. I do not need Tiles.
The only thing I want to do is set Markers on Coordinates and move it around.

Has anybody a solution for this?

cheers dmk